# Discrepancy in results size

Tags: support, api-v2.2, search

I just started using the Stack Overflow API. I want to collect all questions related to a specific keyword.

My code iterates over all result pages by increasing the `&page=N` parameter while `'has_more'` is `true`.  However, I noticed a discrepancy in results between the result I find when I search for the term on the site and when using the API.
For example, when I search for GDPR on stackoverflow.com I get 1,449 results. When I use the API I get 855 results.

This is my filter: `&filter=!-PM0x_wtQ*dB)nch99.Yykxk*OOLMzj.H`

I still have enough quota.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce (sort of):

- [Search on the main site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gdpr&searchOn=1): 1,449 results
- [Searching with the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=gdpr&filter=!9_bDE.BDp&site=stackoverflow&run=true): 857 results

  - I use a different filter which shows the total number of results at the bottom, but that doesn't matter:

  [image]

What happens here is explained in the API documentation, if you look closely:

> ### Usage of /search/advanced GET
>
> #### Discussion
>
> Searches a site for any **questions** which fit the given criteria.

(emphasis mine).

If you [limit your site search to questions only, with the `is:q` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gdpr+is%3Aq&searchOn=1), you get 857 results as well. To search for answers as well, you need another API method: [`/search/excerpts`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search) to be precise.